# Pegar valor de variável em outra form visual basic

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Estou com um problema para conseguir pegar o valor de uma `variável` de outro `form`. Tentei seguir alguns tutoriais do macoratti mas nenhum dos 3 que tinham lá funcionaram.

No caso, eu tenho o `form1` e o `form2`, o segundo encontra em um `txt` o valor de um registrador para comunicação serial e preciso desse valor na `form1` para enviar como mensagem.

O código está bem grande, por isso achei melhor não postá-lo.
O link para a página do Macoratti que segui é [esse](http://www.macoratti.net/10/06/vbn_vef1.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma propriedade pública no `form2` e acesse-a pelo `form1`.

Exemplo:

```
Public Partial Class form2
    Inherits Form
    Public Property Informacao() As String
        Get
            Return m_Informacao
        End Get
        Private Set
            m_Informacao = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Informacao As String

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub buttonOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Informacao = "Alguma coisa"
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Utilização no `form1`

```
Dim frm As New Form2()
frm.Show()
Dim info As String = frm.Informacao
```

Comment: Deu certo, creio que estava inserindo no lugar errado a declaração da variável. Muito obrigado jbueno